# How to 'add' cookie only for angular.http request

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I need to emulate some state in my developer utility, and for it I need to pass some special cookie to the http request which made via angular $http module.

Code for making http request looks simple:

```
if (condition){
    var headers = getHeaders();

    if (headers !== 'undefined'){
       config['headers'] = headers;
    }
}
return $http(config);
```

So looks like I should add some field to the this config. But I can't find any related data about this in [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) docs.

I do not want to set cookie 'to the browser' becase I want to pass it only for some several requests performed asynchronously.

Is it real to nmake it with angular.js?